# Trying to append common values to specific numbers in an array. PYTHON

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, append

So basically I'm trying to append numbers in a tuple like array the another number is in a specific position.
Input will be:

```
list1 = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]
```

This is what I want:

```
(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [0, 4, 6, 7, 9])
```

---

```
list1 = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]
list2 =[0, 1]
for k in list2:
    coollist = []
    for i in list1:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            if k == j[0]:
                coollist.append(j[1])
            if k==j[1]:
                coollist.append(j[0])
print(coollist)
```

What I'm getting: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: what do you expect when you iterate over empty list coollist?

Comment: Is there a question? `coollist = [];  for i in coollist:` - there is nothing in `coollist` --> no iterations.

Comment: If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like stepping through execution, setting breakpoints, and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: I thought I was iterating over list2 and I was trying to append a empty value to coollistt. coolest is just an empty list That I'm trying to add the values to.

Comment: Well when you're doing `for i in coollist` you are iterating through coollist.

Comment: OMG that's a mistake lol. it's supposed to be list1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a working solution

```
list1 = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]
list2 =[0, 1]
for n,k in enumerate(list(list2)):
    coollist = []
    for i in list1:
        if k == i[0]:
            coollist.append(i[1])
    list2[n] =(list2[n],[_ for _ in coollist])
print(list2) # output [(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 6, 7, 9])]
```